# How to get uploaded files after form submit using uploadify?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, file-upload, uploadify

**Question:**

I have a form with a textbox, file browse(uploadify) and a submit button. I am submitting this form via AJAX. When I select a file using file browser, it is automatically uploaded to a folder defined against **folder** option. Now after submitting form, I want to save data into database. I am able to get other fields data after post but unable to get uploaded files. I want an array of uploaded files in $_POST after submitting form like this:

```
$_POST( 'fullname'=>'ABC', 'uploaded_files' => array( '/uploads/abc.doc', '/uploads/xyz.doc' ) );
```

How it is possible ?

**I have following implementation so far.**

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery('.FileUpload').uploadify({
        'uploader'  : '/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        'script'    : '/uploadify/uploadify.php',
        'cancelImg' : '/uploadify/cancel.png',
        'folder'    : '/uploads',
        'auto'      : true,
        'queueID'   : 'fileQueue',
        'removeCompleted':false
      });
```

**HTML:**

```
<form action='save.php' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>

Name: <input type='text' name='fullname' id='fullname'>

Source File: <input type='file' name='photos' id='photos' class='FileUpload'>
<div id="fileQueue"></div>

<input type='submit' name='submit' id='submit'>

</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using javascript you can add some inputs to your form to trace the uploaded files. For example you can put:

```
<input type='hidden' name='files[]' value="FILENAME1">
<input type='hidden' name='files[]' value="FILENAME2">
<input type='hidden' name='files[]' value="FILENAME3">
```

Comment: It means, whenever I upload a file using uploadify, I should add a hidden field in form with file name using jquery ??

Comment: @Student Yes. It is one of the possible solutions.

Comment: I tried this. I added hidden field each time I upload a file using **onCompelete** option. But when I submit the form then these hidden fields are not posted correctly with zend form. I am getting form values in zend using `$form->getValues();`. The problem is that zend is not considering dynamically added values into form. However I am able to get these values using `$_POST` but is not ideal. Is there any other solution.. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Remember that uploadify has an [`onComplete`](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/events/oncomplete-2/) event that can return data back from your `'script'` parameter.

So, when uploadify passes the file off, you can then have the script return the path to the file storage location, and then retrieve/store it in your form based on what was passed back in the `onComplete` event. (This would be the **response** portion of the `onComplete` callback)

From there, you can populate hidden form fields that are them submitted with the form (as AurelioDeRosa has demonstrated) and populated with the **response** value(s).

Comment: Thanks for your reply..I tried this. I added hidden field each time I upload a file using **onCompelete** option. But when I submit the form then these hidden fields are not posted correctly with zend form. I am getting form values in zend using `$form->getValues();`. The problem is that zend is not considering dynamically added values into form. However I am able to get these values using `$_POST` but is not ideal. Is there any other solution.. Thanks

Comment: @Student: I'm not 100% sure about zend, but you might be able to hard-code/pre-define the hidden fields, then just adjust them when necessary. (i.e. if uploadify is allowed to upload 10 files max, create 10 "placeholder" hidden fields you can populate as files are added to the upload queue that you can populate as `onComplete` comes back with values.)

Comment: @Student: A little convoluted, but a possible work-around. There's probably a better way, but (like I said) I'm not 100% confident in a method using zend; I tend to stick with nuts-n-bolts php and $_POST.

Comment: Yes you are right. I can add these hidden fields in zend form. But If we have a limit of 10 files to upload, we have to create 10 hidden fields in zend form. It looks extra work.. May be I will find an other better solution.. Thanks...

Comment: Problem is solved using `$request->getPost();` instead of `$form->getValues();`.... `$request->getPost();` is getting values of dynamically added elements as well...