# How to get form object whos element is clicked

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, file-upload, uploadify

I am uploading file using jQuery uploadify plugin. [Each time I upload a file, a hidden field is created in the form with uploaded file path on server.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7700989/how-to-get-uploaded-files-after-form-submit-using-uploadify/7701000#7701000) When I submit the form, I store this file path in database by getting it from hidden field. It is working for me. One problem is that I am hard coding form object in `onComplete` function of uploadify.

Here is my code:

**jQuery:**

```
     $('.FileUpload').uploadify({
        'uploader'  : '/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        'script'    : '/uploadify/uploadify.php',
        'cancelImg' : '/uploadify/cancel.png',
        'folder'    : '/uploads',
        'auto'      : true,
        'queueID'   : 'fileQueue',
        'removeCompleted':false,
        'onComplete'  : function(event, ID, fileObj, response, data) {
                            // It is hard coded here. It may create probelems 
                            // if there are multiple file upload buttons.
                            // How can I do this with '$(this)' keyword or something
                            $('.SingleFileUpload').parents('form').append( '<input type="hidden" name="uploaded_file" value="' + response + '">' );
                        }
      });
```

How can I get only form who's file browse button is clicked in `onComplete()` function. I think you got my point?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should work if you replace `$('.SingleFileUpload')` with `$(event.target)`

Comment: Thanks. It gives me a direction. I posted my complete solution as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using following:

```
$(event.target).closest('form').append( '<input type="hidden" name="uploaded_file" value="' + response + '">' );
```